# Knockout "with" binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I am trying to display descendant elements in array using "with" binding.
But it displays only last items in "exercises" and I want to see all of them. How is it possible to fix this?
And after that, how can I make each item in array editable?

My ViewModel:

```
    function AppViewModel() {   
    var self = this;

    self.workouts = ko.observableArray([
        {name: "Workout1", exercises:{
            name: "Exercise1.1",
            name: "Exercise1.2",
            name: "Exercise1.3"
        }},
        {name: "Workout2", exercises:{
            name: "Exercise2.1",
            name: "Exercise2.2",
            name: "Exercise2.3"
        }},
        {name: "Workout3", exercises:{
            name: "Exercise3.1",
            name: "Exercise3.2",
            name: "Exercise3.3"
        }},        
        {name: "Workout4", exercises:{
            name: "Exercise3.1",
            name: "Exercise3.2",
            name: "Exercise3.3"
        }},        

]);

    self.removeWorkout = function() {
        self.workouts.remove(this);
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

The View:

```
<div class="content">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: workouts">
        <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"> </span>
         <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeWorkout">Remove</a>
         <ul data-bind="with: exercises">
            <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Here's this code at jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9TrbE/

Thanks!

Comment: Make a foreach: excersises Inside With binding?

Comment: *instead of with binding

Comment: Tried to use foreach, without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exercises property you declared as an object should be an array.

```
self.workouts = ko.observableArray([
    {name: "Workout1", exercises:[
        { name: "Exercise1.1" },
        { name: "Exercise1.2" },
        { name: "Exercise1.3" }
    ]},
]);
```

So you can use this view :

```
<div class="content">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: workouts">
        <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"> </span>
         <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeWorkout">Remove</a>
         <ul data-bind="foreach: exercises">
            <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Declaring :

```
var exercises = {
    name: "Exercise1.1",
    name: "Exercise1.2",
    name: "Exercise1.3"
};
```

Is like doing that  :

```
var exercises = {
    name: "Exercise1.1",
};
exercises.name: "Exercise1.2";
exercises.name: "Exercise1.3";
```

Comment: Ok, but isn't it possible to have it declared like an object? Later I want to link "sets" and "reps" to each "exercise" so I thought it may be better to have it like object.

Comment: @Yuriy No, because you're trying to have an object with `n` properties all of the same name. How do you distinguish `exercises.name` from `exercises.name`? Each `exercise` is an object, which can have properties `name` `sets` and `reps`, but `exercises` (plural) is an array of `exercise` objects.

Comment: I've got it. Ok, I tried to change exercises property to be an array, but still no success. And here's the output I get now. http://jsfiddle.net/vDDky/

Comment: @Damien Used foreach along with declaring exercises as array and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get it with this
Here's this code at jsfiddle

```
self.workouts = ko.observableArray([
    {name: "Workout1", exercises:[
        { name: "Exercise1.1" },
        { name: "Exercise1.2" },
        { name: "Exercise1.3" }
    ]},
]);
```

`http://jsfiddle.net/9TrbE/8/